# Simple Linked List Core Dumps

Tags: c++, linked-list

novice at C++ trying to grasp/implement by first linked list in the form of a maze/game that users can navigate through.  My code below compiles but crashes horrible after I type in a string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

//main node, label is current room user is in
struct RoomNode
{
    std::string label;
    RoomNode* north;
    RoomNode* south;
    RoomNode* east;
    RoomNode* west;
    //constructor, all locations set to NULL by default
    RoomNode(std::string name)
    {
        label = name;
        north = NULL;
        south = NULL;
        east = NULL;
        west = NULL;
    }

};

int main()
{
    bool exitFound = false;
    std::string userDirection; 
    std::string userExit = "EXIT";
    //the maze has 8 rooms
    //8th room has exit
    //create necessary nodes
    RoomNode *head;
    head = new RoomNode("Beginning (Room 1)");
    RoomNode *secondRoom = new RoomNode("Room 2");
    RoomNode *thirdRoom = new RoomNode("Room 3");
    RoomNode *fourthRoom = new RoomNode("Room 4");
    RoomNode *fifthRoom = new RoomNode("Room 5");
    RoomNode *sixthRoom = new RoomNode("Room 6");
    RoomNode *seventhRoom = new RoomNode("Room 7");
    RoomNode *eighthRoom = new RoomNode("EXIT");

    //build linked list
    //RoomNode contructor defaults all directions to NULL
    head->east = secondRoom;
    secondRoom->south = thirdRoom;
    secondRoom->west = head;
    thirdRoom->west = fifthRoom;
    thirdRoom->east = fourthRoom; //fourth room is dead end
    thirdRoom->north = secondRoom;
    fifthRoom->north = head;
    fifthRoom->south = sixthRoom;
    sixthRoom->west = seventhRoom;
    seventhRoom->north = fourthRoom;
    seventhRoom->south = eighthRoom;

        std::cout << "You must navigate your way out of the maze." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Do so by specifying the direction you would" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "like to travel (East, West, North, or South)." << std::endl;


    RoomNode *traverse = head; //point to beginning of list

    do
    {
        std::cout << "You are currently in room " << traverse-> label << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Enter the direction you wish to travel in (lowercase)." << std::endl;
        getline(std::cin, userDirection);

        if (userDirection != "east" || userDirection != "north" || 
            userDirection != "west" || userDirection != "south")
        {
            std::cout << "You did not enter a valid direction." << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Please try again, this time entering" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "north, east, west, or south." << std::endl;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            if (userDirection == "west")
            {
                if (traverse->west == NULL)
                {
                    std::cout << "Sorry, the door in that direction is boarded shut!" << std::endl;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cout << "You moved " << userDirection << "!" << std::endl;
                    traverse = traverse->west; //update current position                    
                }

                if (traverse->label == userExit)
                {
                    std::cout << "You found the exit! Congratulations!" << std::endl;
                    std::cout << "You were able to escape the serpent!" << std::endl;
                    exitFound = true;
                    break;
                }   
            }
            else if (userDirection == "north")
            {
                if (traverse->north == NULL)
                {
                    std::cout << "Sorry, the door in that direction is boarded shut!" << std::endl;
                    break;                  
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cout << "You moved " << userDirection << "!" << std::endl;
                    traverse = traverse->north; 
                }

                if (traverse->label == userExit)
                {
                    std::cout << "You found the exit! Congratulations!" << std::endl;
                    std::cout << "You were able to escape the serpent!" << std::endl;
                    exitFound = true;
                    break;                  
                }
            }
            else if (userDirection == "east")
            {
                if (traverse->south == NULL)
                {
                    std::cout << "Sorry, the door in that direction is boarded shut!" << std::endl;
                    break;                  
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cout << "You moved " << userDirection << "!" << std::endl;
                    traverse = traverse->east; 
                }

                if (traverse->label == userExit)
                {
                    std::cout << "You found the exit! Congratulations!" << std::endl;
                    std::cout << "You were able to escape the serpent!" << std::endl;
                    exitFound = true;
                    break;                  
                }               
            }
            else if (userDirection == "south")
            {
                if (traverse->south == NULL)
                {
                    std::cout << "Sorry, the door in that direction is boarded shut!" << std::endl;
                    break;                  
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cout << "You moved " << userDirection << "!" << std::endl;
                    traverse = traverse->south; 
                }

                if (traverse->label == userExit)
                {
                    std::cout << "You found the exit! Congratulations!" << std::endl;
                    std::cout << "You were able to escape the serpent!" << std::endl;
                    exitFound = true;
                    break;                  
                }
            }
        }

    } while (exitFound);

    delete head;
    delete traverse;
    delete secondRoom;
    delete thirdRoom;
    delete fourthRoom;
    delete fifthRoom;
    delete sixthRoom;
    delete seventhRoom;
    delete eighthRoom;

    return 0;
}
```

I'm aware that it could be shortened quite a bit but my main focus is trying to get the linked list to work, can anybody help me out? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this happens when it encounters "delete traverse".
traverse points to something else, not its own object, in this case head, which has already been deleted.

This is the reason it falls out of the loop after input:

```
    if (userDirection != "east" || userDirection != "north" || 
        userDirection != "west" || userDirection != "south")
```

Please consider using && instead of ||, so that a valid value of userDirection will cause the expression to be false and the flow to fall through to the else block for direction processing.

Also, exitFound is false, so it will probably exit the loop after the first iteration.  Maybe the while condition needs to be while (!exitFound).